# Dominating of the modulus of solutions of a polynomial by coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f(x)∈C[x]$,$$f(x)=x^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i x^i$$
if the coefficients $a_i$ satisfies
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|a_i|≤1$$
Prove that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|ξ_i|≤n$$,where $ξ_i$ are the roots of $f=0$.

I don't know if someone have asked this question.I think it may just be an easy application of Rouché's Theorem,but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Lagrange (?) bound on polynomial roots, 
$$
R=\max(1,\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|a_i|)
$$
is an upper bound for the magnitude of the roots of the polynomial. By assumption, $R=1$ and thus
$$
|ξ_i|\le 1
$$
for all roots, which is stronger than in the sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|ξ_i|\le n.
$$

---

For any root $|ξ|>1$ one gets the estimate
$$
0=|p(ξ)|\ge|ξ|^n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|a_i|·|ξ|^i\ge|ξ|^n-|ξ|^{n-1}·\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|a_i|
$$
which implies
$$
|ξ|\le\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|a_i|
$$
if the coefficient sum is larger than $1$.